# Find a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that for any $y \in \Bbb R$, there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_i} \}$ converging to $y$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Find a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that for any $y \in \Bbb R$, there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_i} \}$ converging to $y$.

I actually have almost zero clue where to start? Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 4):

An enumeration of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I'm sorry, would you mind elaborating? How does that work? Thanks !

Comment: @Surb - very well explained :)

Comment: @Surb In your comment, you don't mean "increasing" ("if $(x_n)$ is an enumeration increasing of $\mathbb{Q}$, ...") — of course there's no such thing.

Comment: @BrianO: Of course you are right. There is no such a thing. Thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Surd, an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$ (that means, a listing of the elements of $\Bbb Q$ - i.e. a sequence in $\Bbb Q$ ).

The reason for this being as follows:

Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, we know that for any $y \in \Bbb R$ there exists a sequence $\{q_n\}\in \Bbb Q$ such that $q_n \to y$. Since the sequence $\{q_n\}$ converges to $y\in \Bbb R$, we then (clearly) must have that every subsequence $\{q_{n_k}\}$ of $\{q_n \} \in \Bbb Q$ converges to the same $y \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: That helps a lot! If I were going to explicitly define one, how would I go about it?

Comment: This can be quite a daunting task as there this usually involves playing around with some kind of numerical analysis, I will try and find you an example now and post it :). The purpose of this question (as done in Real Analysis), is usually simply to help you understand (theoretically) why this is possible :).

Comment: See this question as an example :). In this one, we first prove that there is a sequence in $\Bbb Q$ that converges to $\sqrt{3}$ (which is in $\Bbb R$). This then directly implies that every subsequence must also converge to $\sqrt{3}$. The second part shows different way you can go about finding such a sequence.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226922/rational-number-that-approximates-sqrt3

Answer (score 0):

Think about the fact that every real number can be arbitrarily approximated by a finite decimal expansion (i.e., a rational number)...

In particular, the density of the rational in the reals is a fundamental, elementary notion from real analysis. Also that the rationals are countable...

This question was similar [Every real number is the limit of some subsequence of a given sequence in the sequence of all rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499171/every-real-number-is-the-limit-of-some-subsequence-of-a-given-sequence-in-the-se)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not necessary, it's easier if every rational occurs in the sequence *infinitely often*. There is a bijection $$f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Q} \text{.}$$ So let the sequence be $$q_n = \text{2nd coordinate of }f(n)\text{.}$$
Given a real $x$, let its decimal expansion be $\Sigma_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i 10^{-i}$. Then each partial sum $x_n = \Sigma_{i=0}^n a_i 10^{-i}$ occurs infinitely often in the sequence $(q_n)$, and we can define the following subsequence:
$$
\begin{align}
n_0 &= \text{least $n$ where $q_n = x_0$,} \\
n_{k+1} &= \text{least $n > n_k$ where $q_n = x_{k+1}$.}
\end{align}
$$
Clearly, $(q_{n_k})_{k\ge 0}$ is a sequence of the partial sums, in order, and $\lim_{k\to \infty} q_{n_k} = x$.