# Find a sequence $(a_n)$ such that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a subsequence $(a_{n_i})$ converging to $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[Find a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that for any $y \in \Bbb R$, there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_i} \}$ converging to $y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513587/find-a-sequence-x-n-such-that-for-any-y-in-bbb-r-there-exists-a-subse)
Now, I wish to prove the very same thing, but what comes to my mind, am I even able to define $$a_n=n\text{-th rational number}$$ because there is not "smallest" number from which to start. Actually the subsequence must be something like $a_{n_i}$ s.t. $n_i$ is increasing, how can i achieve such thing. When i enumerate $\mathbb{Q}$, how am i able to construct such sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enumeration of $\mathbb Q$ is a bijection $b\colon\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb Q$. Having that bijection, you can say that $b(1)$ is the first rational number, that $b(2)$ is the second rational number, and so on. So, yes, now you can talk about the $n$<sup>th</sup> rational number.

---

Note that in order to find a sequence such that, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, there is a subsequence converging to it, you don't need all this. Just consider the sequence$$1+1,1+\frac12,2+\frac12,1+\frac13,2+\frac13,3+\frac13,1+\frac14,2+\frac14,3+\frac14,4+\frac14,\ldots$$

Comment: So then, do i just define a new ordering on $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @MichalDvořák Yes.

Comment: I've added another answer.

Comment: That actually makes things clear, thanks for the solution!

Comment: Actually, is there a way to write that in a closed form? (the sequence you gave)

Comment: @MichalDvořák Right now, I don't see how to do that. Perhaps that you might post it as another question.